# How to add an object to a bucket in Ceph / Amazon S3

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, put, ceph

As per the documentation(http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/radosgw/s3/objectops/),
PUT /{bucket}/{object} HTTP/1.1 is the syntax to add an object to a bucket. How do I specify object which is a file to be added to the bucket?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using HTTP rather than any s3 compatible client, like s3cmd?

Comment: I m not sure if Ceph works with S3cmd

Comment: if you are using RGW with the S3 interface, it should... beats writing protocol calls if all you want is to upload files to an S3 bucket.